# .net component installer for COM interop

Tags: c#, com, installation

I have a .net component that will be called by unmanaged code. I want to create an installer for the .net component that will in one step..

-install it to the desired directory
-generate the tlb file
-run the regasm command

The deployers of this component dont have knowledge of the .net framework.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Does InstallSheild of other installers not support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type library only needs to be deployed if you want your client to use the component themselves when they write their own code using your COM server.  That's unlikely given your description of their skills.  If required anyway, you are better off simply deploying the .tlb yourself instead of auto-generating it during install.

Your client won't have Regasm.exe on their machine, it is only available in the Windows SDK.  Nevertheless, registering ComVisible components is a standard capability of MSI.  You can create your own installer that registers the component with a Visual Studio Setup project.  Set the Register property to "vsdrpCOM".

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but I think something like this would work:

Add an [Install.Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) class to your component, override it's `Install` and `Uninstall` methods and use [RegisterAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) to register the `Assembly`.
Then create a Visual Studio setup project and add a custom action to run your Installer methods during the setup.

Actually, here's a thread discussing just this and there's a comprehensive answer in there:  http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/18/90440.aspx